# Macros for formatting & breaking classnames, file paths etc?

Tags: paths

I would like to format classes, file paths, directory paths, method names and so on in my document. At the very basic each of those should be formatted as \texttt. However, the rules for when LaTeX can line break them are different. For example:

- Classes: break at '.'. For example "java.util.String" could be broken 2 places
- File & directory paths: break at '/'. For example "C:\a\b\c" could be broken 3 places
- Method names: break at spaces. For example "public getText()" could be broken 1 place

How would I go about doing this? The defs below is a starting point, but it doesn't provide any breaking behavior since LaTeX doesn't break \texttt by default.

```
\newcommand{\class}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\method}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
..
```

Comment: use the url package

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the help of the `url` package we can define three new commands: `\class`, `\filedir`, and `\method`.

First of all we load the package `url` as follows:

```
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{url}
```

The `obeyspaces` option is needed otherwise all spaces inside `\url`-like commands are ignored and the option `spaces` is needed otherwise we won't be able to break lines at whitespaces.

These are the definitions:

```
\DeclareUrlCommand\class{%
  \renewcommand{\UrlBigBreaks}{\do\.}%
  \renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{\do\.}%
  }
\DeclareUrlCommand\filedir{%
  \renewcommand{\UrlBigBreaks}{\do\\}%
  \renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{\do\\}%
  }
\DeclareUrlCommand\method{%
  \renewcommand{\UrlBigBreaks}{}%
  \renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{}%
  }
```

In the first case, we are creating a command that allows breaks only when a `.` is encountered. In the second one a command that allows breaks only when a `\` is encountered. In the third case we leave the list blank since spaces are already allowed by the `spaces` option at loading time.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\class{%
  \renewcommand{\UrlBigBreaks}{\do\.}%
  \renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{\do\.}%
  }
\DeclareUrlCommand\filedir{%
  \renewcommand{\UrlBigBreaks}{\do\\}%
  \renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{\do\\}%
  }
\DeclareUrlCommand\method{%
  \renewcommand{\UrlBigBreaks}{}%
  \renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{}%
  }

\begin{document}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text tex \class{java.util.String}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text tex \filedir{C:\a\b\c}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text \method{public getText()}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: With the url package is there a way to add e.g. parenthesis to the methods automatically so that \method{hello} becomes "hello()"?

Comment: @johnrl Yes. In the definition of `\method` add a line `\renewcommand{\UrlRight}{()}%`

Comment: thanks, but that seems to insert two different paren sizes. In particular, the right paren is larger than the left. I solved with `\renewcommand{\UrlRight}{$()$}%`, but I'm not sure it's the best way.

Comment: @johnrl I can't reproduce that issue. For me, both parenthesis have same size.

Comment: Strange. However, it works with the math-mode hack, so I'm happy. Thanks!

Comment: Another little improvement: how to only add the parenthesis if not manually added? E.g. `\method{hello}` should produce `hello()` but `\method{hello(int)}` should produce `hello(int)` and not `hello(int)()`.

Comment: @johnrl I don't know how this can be implemented.