# Using commands inside \url?

Tags: macros, urls

How does one use commands inside \url{..}?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}   
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand{\placeholder}[1]{\textcolor{red!60!black}{\textlangle#1\textrangle}}

\begin{document}
\url{Hello \placeholder{name}}.
\end{document}
```

which produces:

```
Hello \placeholder{name}.
```

and not the expected:

```
Hello <name>.
```

This is a contrived example. In reality I have defined several custom url commands ([Macros for formatting & breaking classnames, file paths etc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152972/macros-for-formatting-breaking-classnames-file-paths-etc)), and it is in those commands that I want to use the placeholder. But I believe the solution for this simpler case is the same as for the custom urlcommands.

Comment: Please provide a bit more information as to what you're looking to achieve and what an argument to the macro `\placeholder` might realistically be expected to look like. E.g., are you looking to typeset a URL string in a certain color, are you trying to "hide" the real URL string with a placeholder, or something else?

Comment: Why can't you use `Hello \texttt{\placeholder{name}}`?

Comment: The definition of `\placeholder` is included in the MWE. It is exactly that which I expect it to look like; dark red text surrounded by < and >. For example, to signify that `domain` is a placeholder in the url `http://domain.com/` I want it to look like this: `http://<domain.com>/`.

Comment: @Herbert \texttt does not break nicely like \url and custom url commands does. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152972/macros-for-formatting-breaking-classnames-file-paths-etc

Comment: Untried, but doesn't `\expandafter\url{\placeholder{xx}}` work?

Comment: @hugovdberg: doesn't seem like it. `\expandafter\url{\placeholder{xx}}` --> `\placeholder{xx}`.

Comment: @johnrl: Especially for domains exists an own RFC: [RFC 2606 - Reserved Top Level DNS Names](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606). You should not use `⟨domain⟩.com`, but `example.(com|net|org)`.

Comment: @johnrl: You should have noted in between that the package `url` was not made for this use. You can add something in the beginning and end with `\UrlLeft` and `\UrlRight`, but not in between. So you must change to a different approach.

Answer (score 5):

`\UrlLeft` and `\UrlRight` can be used for the purpose of adding angle brackets, see section "6 Yet more flexibility" `url`'s [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf). Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{%
  \def\UrlLeft{\langle}%
  \def\UrlRight{\rangle}%
}

\begin{document}
  \url{http://www.example.org/}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\langle` and `\rangle` are used instead of the text mode commands, because the implicitly used math mode of `\url`.

### Package `hyperref`

Command `\url` is redefined to add additional code needed by `hyperref`, thus it cannot be redefined directly. The old meaning is stored and uses as `\Hurl`, thus this is the macro that can be redefined:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}% loads package url
\DeclareUrlCommand\Hurl{%
  \def\UrlLeft{\langle}%
  \def\UrlRight{\rangle}%
}

\begin{document}
  \url{http://www.example.org/}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result hyperref]

The angle brackets are part of the link, but not part of the URL for the link.
If the brackets should not be colorized by option `colorlinks`, then the color could be reset to `\normalcolor` for the fences:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}% loads package url
\DeclareUrlCommand\Hurl{%
  \def\UrlLeft{\begingroup\normalcolor\langle\endgroup}%
  \def\UrlRight{\begingroup\normalcolor\rangle\endgroup}%
}

\begin{document}
  \url{http://www.example.org/}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result hyperref normalcolor brackets]

If the current color should be used instead of `\normalcolor`, then it becomes a little more complicate. Package `xcolor` has the concept of a current color `.` and this color can be saved via `\colorlet` and uses later inside the url command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}% loads package url

\LetLtxMacro\OriginalUrl\url
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\url}{%
  \colorlet{beforeurl}{.}%
  \OriginalUrl
}
\DeclareUrlCommand\Hurl{%
  \def\UrlLeft{\begingroup\color{beforeurl}\langle\endgroup}%
  \def\UrlRight{\begingroup\color{beforeurl}\rangle\endgroup}%
}

\begin{document}
  \color{blue}\url{http://www.example.org/}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result hyperref currentcolor]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how to use this when the purpose is to only put a part of the url in brackets? I may not have been clear about that in my post. I have reformulated it to be more clear.

Comment: @johnrl: Then it's not a URL. There are many packages vor verbatim stuff (`alltt`, `listings`, ...).

Comment: do you know any better solutions to do this then? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152972/macros-for-formatting-breaking-classnames-file-paths-etc

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the requirements, but here is some custom `\verb` more or less extracted from some code I needed on another occasion. As the `alltt` environment from the `alltt` package it treats `\`, `{`, and `}` normally. Additionally it treats spaces as in regular `tex` source, thus allowing line breaks. And this is an inline, not display "environment".

To be used as `\myverb!stuff!` or `\myverb+stuff+` etc... (no empty line in argument, to force multiple spaces, use `\ \ \` for example as in standard text).

> [image: my verb]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\makeatletter
% DEFINITIONS FOR SOME CUSTOM INLINE VERBATIM À LA ALLTT
% customize as desired:
\def\MicroFont{\normalfont\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font 45 }

\def\mydo@noligs #1% 
% jfbu: modification to \do@noligs  (added space after `#1) is mandatory if
% space is not made active via \@vobeyspaces in verbatim stuff.
{%
    \catcode `#1\active 
    \begingroup \lccode `\~=`#1\relax 
    \lowercase {\endgroup \def ~{\leavevmode \kern \z@ \char `#1 }}%
}%

% custom inline verbatim allowing line-breaks and like in alltt environment, \,
% { and } have their standard behavoir. For example an hyphenation point may be
% added with \-. NOTA BENE: spaces are treated as elsewhere, thus multiple
% spaces in source collapsed into only one in printed result. Line breaks are
% possible. 
\def\myverb 
{%
  \relax \ifmmode\hbox\else\leavevmode\null\fi
  \bgroup \MicroFont
  \let\do\mydo@noligs  \verbatim@nolig@list
  \let\do\@makeother   \dospecials 
  \catcode32 10 
  \catcode92 0 \catcode123 1 \catcode125 2
  \frenchspacing
  \@myverb 
}% 
\def\@myverb #1{\catcode`#1\active\lccode`\~`#1\lowercase{\let~\egroup}}%

\makeatother

\newcommand{\placeholder}[1]{\textcolor{red!60!black}{\textlangle#1\textrangle}}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\myverb+Hello \placeholder{name}
Hello \placeholder{name}
Hello \placeholder{name}
Hello \placeholder{name}
Hello \placeholder{name}
Hello \placeholder{name}
Hello \placeholder{name}
Hello \placeholder{name}+ and this works also in math mode $a^n
+\myverb?b^n=c^n?$. Back to normal.
\end{document}
```

---

I would try

```
\newcommand{\urlholder}[1]{\textcolor{red!60!black}{\textlangle\url{#1}\textrangle}}
```

mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}   
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand{\urlholder}[1]{\textcolor{red!60!black}{\textlangle\url{#1}\textrangle}}

\begin{document}

Hello \urlholder{name and \name}

\end{document}
```

> [image: url holder]

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately this does not work as intended. I want the whole sentence to be a URL, not just the name. And of course that should not be hardcoded.

Comment: which sentence?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated the example. Please recheck.

Comment: well, then it's not a `URL`. So you just want to achieve some verbatim printing?

Comment: I was advised to use the URL package for defining custom verbatim breaking here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152972/macros-for-formatting-breaking-classnames-file-paths-etc - so yes.